# Usar la variable de un método en otro, dentro de la misma clase

Tags: java, java-8

Necesito calcular el precio con descuento con el precio que se transformó a positivo en la validación del método setPrecio.
El código lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
    if (precio<0){
        precio = precio * -1;
        System.out.println("Convertido en positivo " +precio);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Positivo: "+ precio);
    }
}

public double calcularPrecioDescuento(double porcentaje){
    return precio = (precio * (porcentaje/100)+precio);
}
```

Resulta que con esto, en el método calcularPrecioDescuento toma el dato de precio sin la validacion, de manera que cuando se ingresa un número negativo el resultado que se obtiene también es negativo.

Comment: ¿Estos métodos están dentro de la misma clase? De ser así deberías publicar toda la clase o un [mre] que permita reproducir el comportamiento actual para saber cual es el problema.

Comment: En la línea 4 al tener una variable local con el mismo nombre que un atributo de la clase, para referirte al atributo de la clase debes hacerlo con this ( `this.precio = -precio;` ). Tampoco hace falta que multipliques por -1, solo haz la asignación poniendo el signo negativo antes del nombre de la variable.

Comment: **Realmente** lo que no entiendo es qué sentido tiene un eventual precio **¿en negativo?** ¿Podrías explicar a qué se debe eso y qué justifica que un precio sea dado como un número negativo? Una de las grandes ventajas de la POO es que nos permite reflejar la realidad de las cosas en objetos, pero a mi esto no me cuadra en ningún contexto **real**. Hasta ahora no he visto, en ninguna tienda, que pongan los precios de los productos en negativo.

Comment: Hola Mirelly, podrías decir por favor si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y en caso de que te hallan sido útiles darles tu voto positivo y marcar como aceptada la que más te ayudó y/o gustó, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las características fundamentales de la **Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO)** es la encapsulación, en pocas palabras esto quiere decir que vas a acceder a las variables internas de la clase mediante propiedades o métodos, de esta forma garantizas que no se acceda directamente a las variables internas de las clases lo cual contribuye entre otras cosas a un código más seguro evitándose así posibles errores de validación.

Siguiendo tu ejemplo debes tener algo como esto:

```
public class MiClase
{
   //aquí vendrían los atributos de la clase, 
   //en otras palabras las variables internas de la clase
   //las cuales deben ser declaradas como privadas 
   //ya que se accederá a ellas mediante métodos y propiedades publicas

   private double precio;

   //Ahora vendría el o los constructores de la clase
   public MiClase(){}

   //Y ahora vendrían los métodos y propiedades públicas
   //que nos van a dar acceso a las variables internas de la clase
   public double getPrecio()
   {
      //Este método nos retorna el atributo precio de la clase
      return this.precio;
   }

   public void setPrecio(double precio)
   { 
      //Este método después de las validaciones
      // correspondientes nos va a guardar en el 
      //campo precio el valor que se recibe como parámetro en este método
      this.precio = precio;

      if (precio < 0)
      {
         this.precio = precio * -1;
      }
   }

   public double calcularDescuento(double porcentaje)
   {
      //Tu código 
   }
}
```

Tu error como tal estaba en que en el **método setPrecio** convertias a positivo el parámetro del método y no el **atributo precio** de la clase ya que debías ponerlo como te expliqué arriba.

Por otra parte la **palabra clave this** es una variable que hace referencia al objeto actual, ejemplo:

```
this.precio = ...
```

Aquí accedes al atributo precio de tu clase.

```
precio = ...
```

En el caso de tu **método calcularPrecioDescuento** te refieres al parámetro del método que casualmente se llama igual que el atributo de la clase, para acceder al precio de la clase debes anteponer la **palabra clave this**, como expliqué arriba.

Para terminar te hablé del encapsulamiento, las otras dos características de la POO son la herencia y el polimorfismo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te pasa es que la lógica es incorrecta.

Si en `setPrecio()` validas determinada condición para luego modificar el precio final (en este caso que el precio que te pasen por parámetro sea menor que 0), este debes guardarlo después de su modificación. Por el contrario, lo que estás haciendo es guardar el precio que te pasan antes de validarlo; y luego de la validación no lo actualizas.

Yo directamente lo guardaría después de todas las validaciones.

```
public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    if (precio < 0) {
        precio = precio * -1;
        System.out.println("Convertido en positivo " + precio);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Positivo: "+ precio);
    }

    // Luego de realizar todas las validaciones y posibles modificaciones
    // es que actualizo el atributo
    this.precio = precio;
}
```